# Is all dependency defined in probability space?

Tags: probability, independence

I'm still confused with the concept of "independent event". Since the set of events is selected, we can calculate all independent events by $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, other pairs are dependent events.

IMO, this kind of dependency is only related to events in **single experiment**. But in practice, some events are dependent across **multiple experiments**. Such as weather forecast, if one day is rainy, the next day would be likely rainy too. This dependency is not defined in probability space. Is it a different concept?

Comment: Yes, "this kind of dependence" is defined via the concept of conditional probability.

Comment: Could you give some details? Are there two kinds of conditional probability?